# What different breakpoint background colors mean in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

When I execute to a certain line of code in eclipse the background color of this line turns green. But sometimes it is a different green (light green). What does that mean?

Comment: attach screenshot to the post or share via imgur.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following is the reason:

`Green` : The debugger is at that particular line at current instance

`Light Green` : The debugger control would come at this line once it moves past current line

`Explanation with Example`: 
I have run some sample program(DBTest.java) in `Debug mode`,

`Green`: Current debug pointer is at line 42, hence its colour is green.

`Light Green`: If you at this point click on line 25 pointer it will be Light Green because control after line 42 is going to line 25.

[image]